# Are all matrices linear operators?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ a matrix, can we think of $A$ as an operator?

In what context do matrices satisfy the definition of operator?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do not satisfy the definition of a linear map. Instead, there is a canonical bijection:

$$\text{Vect}(\mathbb{K}^m,\mathbb{K}^n) \to \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$$

where $\text{Vect}(\mathbb{K}^m,\mathbb{K}^n)$ is the set of linear maps from $\mathbb{K}^m$ to $\mathbb{K}^n$. It is given by mapping a linear map $f : \mathbb{K}^m \to \mathbb{K}^n$ to the matrix $(f(e_1), \dots, f(e_m))$. Its inverse maps a matrix $A$ to the map $f$ with $f(v) = Av$ for all $v\in \mathbb{K}^m$.

So, it doesn't matter, whether we study matrices or linear maps, at least in this case. If you consider other vector spaces without 'standard bases' it gets more complicated.

Comment: Sorry, does your first sentence really say that matrices do not satisfy the definition of a linear map?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer Yes, and they technically really don't (It is a small lie if you say that they do). But their image under the inverse mapping specified above is linear.

Comment: Alright. Can you humour me and point out to me which of the parts of the definition of a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) a matrix does not satisfy?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer A matrix is a map $\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{1,\dots,n\} \to \mathbb{K}$. I don't think I have to continue... (That's not a map $V\to W$ of vector spaces $V,W$ obviously)

Comment: An $n \times m$ matrix with real entries is a map $\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. So please do continue.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer: The point here is that a grid of numbers is not **literally the same thing as** a function from the set $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Stefan's answer describes how one can you can **turn** the former into the latter in a canonical way, if you have a chosen basis.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer What Zev said. It (saying a matrix IS a linear map) is only a small lie, nothing serious. We identify different things in math all the time, but you should usually be aware of it, when you are doing that.

Comment: Honestly, I really really don't understand how a matrix is a map $\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{1,\dots,n\} \to \mathbb{K}$. It seems to me that it takes  vectors of arbitrary real numbers as argument not just integer pairs in these finite sets...?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer This says, that the matrix is an array of elements in $\mathbb{K}$. It takes a pair of numbers $(i,j)$ with $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}, j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and gives you the element at row $i$ and column $j$. You can actually take any set instead of $\mathbb{K}$. You could have matrices of whatever objects you like. (but then they "are" no longer 'linear maps')

Comment: I will think about this some time. For now I do understand what you meant in your previous comment but I still don't see why a matrix does not define a linear map.

Comment: In particular, if $A$ is such a matrix and $x$ some vector and we let $Ax$ be the usual multiplication then this seems to me is not a map $\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{1,\dots,n\} \to \mathbb{K}$ but a map $\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: But I would like to be convinced otherwise, of course.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer That is precisely what the (inverse) mapping in my answer does: mapping a matrix $A$ to the map $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto Ax$. But we shouldn't discuss this here in the comments any further, I think.

Comment: I think \text{Vect} is a rather poor choice of notation. The operator $\operatorname{Vect}$ sometimes denotes vector fields, and I don't think I have ever seen it used to denote linear maps of vector fields. I think $\operatorname{Hom}$ or $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb K}$ or even an upper case $L$ would be preferable.

Comment: @PVAL If I want to be precise, I would write $\text{Vect}_{\mathbb{K}}$ of course. The notation $\mathcal{A}(A,B)$ is simply one notation for the set of morphisms $A\to B$ in some (locally small) category $\mathcal{A}$. This notation used for example in the 3 volumes of "Handbook of categorical algebra" by Francis Borceux.

Answer (score 0):

*In addition to Stefan Perko's answer..*

The square matrices are not linear maps.
They rather form an algebra:
The simplest examples of unital C*-algebras.

Now, there is the Gelfand-Naimark theorem:
It says that they can be interpreted as continuous linear operators over some Hilbert space.
If I'm not mistaken, this turns out to be the canonical bijection described by Stefan Perko.